# REVOKE insert on a specific table form a user in my sql

Tags: mysql, insert

i want to revoke insert on a specific table form a user in mysql
and I try this code before:

`use varian_db;
REVOKE INSERT ON 'gevhm_users' FROM 'varian_user';`

but mysql returned this error :

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''gevhm_users' FROM 'varian_user'' at line 1`

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify full path of database name and table name when granting or revoking privileges to/from such user. And also write user name in correct format. Your statement should like this:

```
REVOKE INSERT ON varian_db.gevhm_users FROM 'varian_user'@'user_ip_address';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

More information: [MySQL Revoke Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/revoke.html)